# Access child of another node from child of a node in XSLT

Tags: xslt

How to access the child node of parent 1 from child node of parent 2 in XSLT?

```
<Test>
    <SOLUTIONS>
        <SOLUTION>
            <OBSERVATIONS>
                <OBSERVATION Key = "1ASED">A1</OBSERVATION>
                <OBSERVATION Key = "2DFED">A2</OBSERVATION>
                <OBSERVATION Key = "3DGEE">A3</OBSERVATION>
            </OBSERVATIONS>
            <ITRs>
                <ITR Key = "ASE1">P1</ITR>
                <ITR Key = "GGEE1">P2</ITR>
                <ITR Key = "GERFECE1">P3</ITR>
            </ITRs>
        </SOLUTION>
        <SOLUTION>
            <OBSERVATIONS>
                <OBSERVATION Key = "ABCD">A1</OBSERVATION>
                <OBSERVATION Key = "EFGH">A2</OBSERVATION>
                <OBSERVATION Key = "IJKL">A3</OBSERVATION>
            </OBSERVATIONS>
            ...
        </SOLUTION>
    </SOLUTIONS>
</Test>
```

For each ITR, I need the observation to be printed. For First ITR inside , I have to link the Key of this to Key of the Observation. So, total 9 records to be displayed.

My XSLT is

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Test/SOLUTIONS/SOLUTION">
    <xsl:for-each select="ITRs/ITR">
      <xsl:variable name="Key_ITRPS" select="@Key"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="/Test/SOLUTIONS/SOLUTION/OBSERVATIONS/OBSERVATION">
            <xsl:variable name="srcKey_A" select="@Key"/>
            <xsl:element name="Relationship">
                <xsl:attribute name="RelCommonKey">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat($Key_ITRPS,$srcKey_A)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The output I require is

```
 RelCommonKey

 ASE11ASED
 ASE12DFED
 ASE13DGEE

 GGEE11ASED
 GGEE12DFED
 GGEE13DGEE

 GERFECE11ASED
 GERFECE12DFED
 GERFECE13DGEE
```

The problem i am facing here is along with the above data, i am evening noticing the Observation Key in the second  too.

the ITR key "ASE1" is also linking to "ABCD, "EFGH", "IJKL" also. Please help me in restricting the data as displayed above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is that your XPath queries are all 'anchored' on the root node, "/Test", what you need to do instead is use the current context and the 'parent' XPath axis to navigate fron the ITR element to the OBSERVATIONS within the same SOLUTION. The following XSLT gives the output you require:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//SOLUTION"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SOLUTION">
    <!-- iterat over the ITRs for this solution -->
    <xsl:for-each select="ITRs/ITR">
      <xsl:variable name="Key_ITRPS" select="@Key"/>
      <!-- iterate over the observations -->
      <xsl:for-each select="../../OBSERVATIONS/OBSERVATION">
        <!-- the ITR Key -->
        <xsl:value-of select="$Key_ITRPS"/>
        <!-- the related observation -->
        <xsl:value-of select="@Key"/>
        <!-- a newline -->
        <xsl:text>
        </xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: :) Thanks Colin. I think I missed out ../../OBSERVATIONS/OBSERVATION. Thanks for the help. +1 to the answer :)

Comment: No problem. If this answers your question, you should mark it as an answer by clicking the 'tick' symbol.